# jquery each function error when getting value

Tags: jquery

I have that Jquery code:

```
$('input[name*="fotos[]"]').each(function (i, ele) {
      alert(ele.val());
});
```

but I get that error in browers:

Error: TypeError: ele.val is not a function

what is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use

`alert($(ele).val());`

or

```
alert($(this).val());
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn `ele` into a jQuery object:

```
alert($(ele).val());
```

Answer (score 2):

The `ele` parameter to the `.each` callback is a single DOM element, not a jQuery object.

You should either:

1. use the native DOM property - `ele.value`, or
2. convert `ele` back into a jQuery object - `$(ele).val()`

NB: within the callback, `this === ele`